# C# Attachments icon to be shown in the web Browser

Tags: c#

How can i show an attachment's icon in web-browser in c# so that the user should know that there is an attachment available in the email like we all have in gmail,yahoo e.t.c
[You can see this in the image i have attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3GZ6.png)

[The picture will let you to develop the logic that when user selects the email he should have an access to the attachments also. I don't know how to let user to know that the email selected also have an attachment in it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb7c5.png)

Comment: what is have you tried? what is the code you wrote? what is the issue you are facing? Welcome to SO Please provide enough details https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you checked the image i have attached ??

Comment: i want to use this kind of icon in my win form application. How should i do that?

Comment: Yes I saw that but that cannot help us to help you...if that so if you are able to get to know that your email has an attachment then add an icon in your code, that should be fine; how are you displaying your emails, tabular view and want a column with attachment icon or detailed email view ad want an icon as mentined in image? and for that i asked what code you have tried!

Comment: i have attached the other image so that you might develop some logic to show the attachment icon on web browser.

Comment: How are you rendering the left panel? I can see that has a formatting like Name, email, some details and then time stamp, there itself you can have one image control and while filling this panel in that loop you can check for having attachment and if yes add the icon or else keep that image control hidden. Hope i am making sense to you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How are you rendering the left panel? I can see that has a formatting like Name, email, some details and then time stamp, there itself you can have one image control and while filling this panel in that loop you can check for having attachment and if yes add the icon or else keep that image control hidden. Hope i am making sense to you.